# how can i pass parameter for Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,

Tags: linq, generics, .net-core, repository, iorderedqueryable

I have the following generic repository function but am unable to pass a parameter for order by

```
Task<List<T>> AdvGetAllAsync(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            List<string> includes = null
            );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably in this way:

```cs
var result = await someRep.AdvGetAllAsync(orderBy: q => q.OrderBy(x => x.SomeField));
```